# Is Jenkins/Hudson ciphered password storage "safe"?

Tags: password, configuration, hudson, password-management

In setting up our Jenkins/Hudson server recently it became clear that it has to store passwords. It seems that it stores the passwords "ciphered" in config.xml I can't see how this would be safe as the chain of secrets has to break somewhere.

- *Can Jenkins' ciphered passwords be considered "safe"?*
- *Is this just security through obscurity?*

I should specify that we're using Jenkins 1.425.

Comment: In this case Hudson has to pass on the passwords to secondary authentication mechanisms so it has to be able to undo it's encryption. Looks like Shane found the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to be AES128 encrypted using a key stored locally.  You're exactly right that it's essentially just a layer of obscurity - conceptually, the only options available in a situation like this are to require a password to be entered at the time the service starts as a decryption key, or to store the key somewhere locally; a good analogue is encrypted SSL certificates for a web server.

The comments in the code for the `hudson.util.Secret` class make clear that they understand the security limitations of this method:

> Glorified String that uses encryption in the persisted form, to avoid accidental exposure of a secret.  Note that since the cryptography relies on Hudson.getSecretKey(), this is not meant as a protection against code running in the same VM, nor against an attacker who has local file system access.

Comment: Are you familiar enough with Hudson to know whether it's possible to force it to require a password on startup?

Comment: @Catskul Doesn't seem like it's possible, given the structure of the decryption stuff - it's meant to be invisible to the user.